# How to use reporting snapshot

Tags: snapshot

I created a reporting snapshot and the results are now available in a custom object. 
How can I make use of this custom snapshot object for reporting?
Should I be creating a new report type and then use it to create a new report?

If yes, will the newly created report(containing snapshot results) be automatically updated with the latest snapshot results and give me trending report/chart?

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think of your reporting snapshot custom object as any other custom object - it has fields and rows (records). Each record typically represents one point in time for one level of summarization from the reporting snapshot source report.

You don't need to create a custom report type; when you created the snapshot object, you simply need to enable reports and SFDC will create the report type for you.

From that point onwards, you can go wild with standard SFDC reporting, charting, dashboards.  You can add formula fields to your analytic snapshot object to help make reporting easier.

Each run of the snapshot adds row(s) to the object so if your report filters are using relative dates (TODAY, THIS WEEK, THIS MONTH, etc), then the new snapshot data is included in the report/dash you build.

> The genius/challenge behind analytic snapshots is learning how to summarize in the source data to yield interesting trending reports in the snapshot object. You also have to be very aware of the analytic snapshot limitations (number of summary rows per job run)